# Datatable yadcf is not working on blank cells or rendered values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, yadcf

Datatable YADCF is not working on blank cells or rendered values. All I am trying to do is to get results where row column contains a blank. I tried rendering the blank value to N/A and it even didn't work for that. Is there a way to filter column through YADCF to filter on rendered value or blank cells?

http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/server_side_source.html

```
 {
   "targets": 19,

   "data": 19,

   "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
     if (data.length > 3) {
       return data;
     } else {
       return ' ';
     }

   }

 }
 yadcf.init(table, [

   {
     column_number: 19,

     data: [{
       value: ' ',
       label: 'Blank'
     }, {
       value: 'Reviewed',
       label: 'Reviewed'
     }, {
       value: 'Need Add Info',
       label: 'Need Add Info'
     }, {
       value: 'Complete',
       label: 'Complete'
     }],
     filter_default_label: "Select"

   }
 ]);
```

Comment: please provide a test page showing your issue

Comment: @Daniel I am using this filter on server side for blank values and for some reason its not working on server side data: http://jsfiddle.net/j7807x2v/13/

Comment: whats the problem in the test page?

Comment: @Daniel I took care of this issue by updating my YADCF js version. Now I am stuck at  one more wierd problem. Multi select filter doesn't work with serverside data in your plugin. Can you share any sample PHP code with me which will help me to modify the multi selected piped value to work just fine  after applying modifications to backend file that returns datatable data?

Comment: dont have any , but you can search github for php projects that made use of the yadcf plugin